# Orthogonal projection of a point into $x+y+z=0$ plane ex.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to W$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto the plane $W$ having the equation $x+y+z=0$.
>
> (a)Find $T(3,8,4)$.
>
> (b)Find the formula for $T$.

I have been stuck on this exercise for hours... How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. The line which passes through $P$ and is orthogonal to $W$ is

$$\vec{r}=(a,b,c)+t(1,1,1)=(a+t,b+t,c+t)$$

At the intersection of the line and $W$ (which is $T(P)$),

\begin{align}
a+t+b+t+c+t&=0\\
t&=\frac{-1}{3}(a+b+c)
\end{align}

So, $$T(a,b,c)=\left(\frac{2a-b-c}{3},\frac{-a+2b-c}{3},\frac{-a-b+2c}{3}\right)$$

Comment: I think you got wrong $\vec{r}=(a,b,c)+t(1,1,1)+(a+t,b+t,c+t)$ it should be instead $\vec{r}=(a,b,c)+t(1,1,1)=(a+t,b+t,c+t)$, right?

Comment: I have a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec{n}(1,1,1)$ is a normal of the plain.

Now, write the equation of the line, which parallel to $\vec{n}$ and $(3,8.6)$ on the line and find a common point of them.

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector of the plane is $\mathbf{n}=<1,1,1>$ and the plane passes through $(0,0,0)$.

So we let the orthogonal projection of $T(3,8,4)$ be $P$ and have a position vector $\mathbf{p}$.

Thus, $$\mathbf{t}+\lambda\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{p}$$

Since $P$ satisfies the plane $x+y+z=0$, so solve for $\lambda$.

$$3+\lambda+8+\lambda+4+\lambda = 0$$

Thus $P=(-2,3,-1)$

Answer (score 0):

Any $\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^3$ can be decomposed into $\mathbf v_\parallel+\mathbf v_\perp$, where $\mathbf v_\parallel=T\mathbf v$, the projection of $\mathbf v$ onto $W$, and $\mathbf v_\perp$ is the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf v$ onto $W^\perp$. Since $W$ is a plane, $W^\perp$ is the line normal to this plane. You should be able to read a vector that spans this space from the defining equation of $W$. The above decomposition says that $T\mathbf v=\mathbf v-\mathbf v_\perp$, so you can find the projection of $\mathbf v$ onto $W$ by finding its projection onto the normal line and subtracting that from $\mathbf v$. For this problem, that’s much less work than trying to work $T$ out directly.